$refs undefined when accessing VueTelInput component
I am working on a Vue.js component that uses the VueTelInput component for phone number input. I am encountering an issue where this.$refs.creationPhoneInput is undefined:
<template>
  <VueTelInput
    ref="creationPhoneInput"
    v-model="phone"
    :defaultCountry="SocietyCountryCode"
    :inputOptions="{ placeholder: 'Teléfono de contacto' }"
    :dropdownOptions="{
      showFlags: true,
      showDialCodeInSelection: true,
      showSearchBox: true
    }"
    @country-changed="(code: CountryCode) => updateCountryCode(code, 'creation')"
  ></VueTelInput>
</template>

<script>
import { nextTick } from 'vue'
import { VueTelInput } from 'vue-tel-input';
import 'vue-tel-input/vue-tel-input.css';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      phone: '',
      SocietyCountryCode: '',
    };
  },
  components: {
    VueTelInput
  },
  async mounted() {
    await this.loadData();
  },
  methods: {
    async loadData() {
      const providerResponse = await fetchProviderData();
      await nextTick();
      if (this.$refs.creationPhoneInput) {
        await this.$refs.creationPhoneInput.choose(providerResponse.country_code);
      } else {
        console.error('creationPhoneInput ref is undefined');
      }
    },
  }
}
</script>

Steps taken:

Ensured VueTelInput is correctly imported and registered.
Used await nextTick() to ensure DOM updates.
Added console logs to debug the presence of this this.$refs and this.$refs.creationPhoneInput. Where the last one is undefined.


you have no other console errors? what are the version numbers for vue and vue-tel-input?

No other console errors. Versions are "vue": "^3.2.0" and "vue-tel-input": "^8.3.1".
Is relevant that this is a view (src/views/providers/Provider.vue) and not a component?

Every .vue file is a component. A "view" is not a technical term, and could be named "page" or something else, it doesn't matter.  Regardless, I can't reproduce.  The ref is defined when I run your code in stackblitz. Please see if you can change something to reproduce
